# XPATH - cannot select grandparent node

Tags: xpath

I am trying to parse a live betting XML feed and need to grab each bet from within the code. In plain English I need to use the tag 'EventSelections' for my base query and 'loop' through these tags on the XML so I grab all that data and it creates and entity for each one which I can use on a CMS.

My problem is I  want to go up two places in the tree to a grandparent node to gather that info. Each EventID refers to the unique name of a game and some games have more bets than others. It's important that I grab each bet AND the EventID associated with it, problem is, this ID is the grandparent each time. Example:

```
    <Sportsbet Time="2013-08-03T08:38:01.6859354+09:30">
<Competition CompetitionID="18" CompetitionName="Baseball">
<Round RoundID="2549" RoundName="Major League Baseball">
<Event EventID="849849" EventName="Los Angeles Dodgers (H Ryu) At Chicago Cubs (T Wood)" Venue="" EventDate="2013-08-03T05:35:00" Group="MTCH">
<Market Type="Match Betting - BIR" EachWayPlaces="0">
<EventSelections BetSelectionID="75989549" EventSelectionName="Los Angeles Dodgers">
<Bet Odds="1.00" Line=""/>
</EventSelections>
<EventSelections BetSelectionID="75989551" EventSelectionName="Chicago Cubs">
<Bet Odds="17.00" Line=""/>
</EventSelections>
```

Does anyone know how I can grab the granparent tags as well?

Currently I am using:

```
//EventSelections (this is the context)
.//@BetSelectionID
.//@EventSelectionName
```

I have tried dozens of different ways to do this including the ../.. operator which won't work either. I'd be eternally grateful for any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you have exactly used the `..` operator?

Comment: I think you just haven't gone far enough up the tree:  `../*` gives you your siblings, `../../*` gives you your aunts and uncles, `../../../*` gives you your grandparents.  This is because `..` walks up one level, but `/` walks down one level ... so you have to go one higher than you are shooting for before you go down again.

Comment: This worked in the end: ..//..//..//@RoundID    I am using Drupal 7 and XPATH feed module and have been working on this problem for about 15 hours. I really appreciate you pushing me in the right direction and so glad I have now got this resolved!! Thanks all. Feel free to email me anyone out there who is stuck with Drupal and XPATH.

Comment: @G.KenHolman You should post that comment as answer and Rich can accept it, so others may get help if they ever have the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just haven't gone far enough up the tree.

`../*` is a two-step location bath with abbreviations, expanded to `parent::node()/child::*` ... so in effect you are going up the tree with the first step, but back down the tree for the second step.

Therefore, `../*` gives you your siblings (parent's children), `../../*` gives you your aunts and uncles (grandparent's children), and `../../../*` gives you your grandparent and its siblings (great-grandparent's children).

For attributes, `../@*` is an abbreviation for `parent::node()/attribute::*` and attributes are attached to elements, they are not considered children.  So you are going sideways, not down the tree in the second step.

Therefore, unlike above, `../@*` gives you your parent's attributes, while `../../@*` gives you your grandparent's attributes.

But using `//` in your situation is really inappropriate. `//` is an abbreviation for `/descendent-or-self::node()/` which walks *all* the way down a tree to the leaves of the tree.  It should be used only in rare occasions (and I cringe when I see it abused on SO questions).

So `..//..//..//@RoundID` may work for you, but it is in effect addressing attributes all over the tree and not just an attribute of your great-grandparent, which is why it is finding the attribute of your grandparent.  `../../@RoundID` should be all you need to get the attribute of your grandparent.

If you torture a stylesheet long enough, it will eventually work for you, but it really is more robust and likely faster executing to address things properly.

Comment: Just for any other novices out there (like me!) Here is the EXACT code I used to grab this data. I'll take a look at your post @G. Ken Holman and see if I can adjust as you mention.

Context: //EventSelections
//@CompetitionID
//@CompetitionName
..//..//..//@RoundID
..//..//..//@RoundName
..//..//@EventID
..//..//@EventName
..//..//@Venue
..//..//@EventDate
..//..//@Group
..//@Type
..//@EachWayPlaces
.//@BetSelectionID
.//@EventSelectionName
.//@Odds
.//@Line
.//@BetSelectionID

Answer (score 2):

You could go with `ancestor::Event/@EventID`, which does exactly you asked for: matches an ancestor element named `Event` and returns it's `EventID` attribute.